# Android ExpandableListView won't expand on return LinearLayout or View

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Im implementing an App where you can choose different Options on the leftside and add them to the main_fragment on the right. Here is the case:

with this code works everything fine:

```
  public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view){

    TextView textview = new TextView(MyFragment.this.getActivity());
    textview.setText("smth");

  return textview;}
```

But I need a checkbox next to my textview. Now, there are several ways of doing this, but unfortunatly none delivers the same result on click: expand!

Here is the first possibility with a simple XML element with a TextView and CheckBox in a LinearLayout:

```
LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);           
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.element, null);
    TextView textview = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview01));
    textview.setText("smth");

    CheckBox cb = ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox01));
return view;
```

or adding the Views programmatically:

```
LinearLayout ln = new LinearLayout(MyFragment.this.getActivity());
TextView textview = new Textview(MyFragment.this.getActivity());
textview.setText("smth");
CheckBox cb = new Checkbox(MyFragment.this.getActivity());
ln.addView(textview);
ln.addView(cb);

return ln;
```

please note, I've shortend the Code to make it easier to read through.
thanx in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox by default catches all focus events of it's parent layout. So to make the layout handle click events(including expand) you need to set checkbox focusability to false:
XML Layout:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

From JAVA code:

```
checkBox.setFocuseble(false);
```

Comment: i'm delighted! Works as desired. I guess, thats just experience! Thanx!

Comment: This helped me when I had a switch in the GroupView. Had to set the Switch's focusability to false. Now, they can expand and collapse, and the switches still work as expected.